# JSON unicode characters conversion

Tags: javascript, php, json, unicode, utf-8

I came across this strange JSON which I can't seem to decode.
To simplify things, let's say it's a JSON string:

```
"\uffffffe2\uffffff94\uffffff94\uffffffe2\uffffff94\uffffff80\uffffffe2\uffffff94\uffffff80 mystring"
```

After decoding it should look as following:

`└── mystring`

JS or PHP doesn't seem to convert it correctly.

```
js> JSON.parse('"\uffffffe2\uffffff94\uffffff94\uffffffe2\uffffff94\uffffff80\uffffffe2\uffffff94\uffffff80 mystring"')
ffe2ff94ff94ffe2ff94ff80ffe2ff94ff80 mystring
```

PHP behaves the same

```
php> json_decode('"\uffffffe2\uffffff94\uffffff94\uffffffe2\uffffff94\uffffff80\uffffffe2\uffffff94\uffffff80 mystring"')
ffe2ff94ff94ffe2ff94ff80ffe2ff94ff80 mystring
```

Any ideas how to properly parse this JSON string would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not valid JSON string  - JSON supports only 4 hex digits after \u. Results from both PHP and JS are correct.

It is not possible decode this using standard functions.

Where did you get this JSON string?

About correct json for string you want to get - it should be `"\u2514\u2500\u2500 mystring"`, or just `"└── mystring"` (json supports any unicode characters in strings except `"` and `\`).

Also if you need to encode some character that require more than two bytes - it will result in two escape codes for example `""` would be `"\ud864\udd0e"` when escaped.

So, If you really need to decode string above - you can fix it before decoding, replacing `\uffffffe2` by `\uffff\uffe2` via regexp (for js it would be something like: `s.replace(/(\\u[A-Fa-f0-9]{4})([A-Fa-f0-9]{4})/gi,'$1\\u$2')` ).

But anyway character codes in string specified above does not look right.

Comment: The JSON comes from `journald` in json format - `journalctl -o json`

Comment: You were right, it was invalid json from `journald` https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1076

Comment: The control characters U+0000 to U+001F _must_ be escaped, too; not only " and \. See [JSON Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) or [RFC 8259](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259).